# Seaborn Catplot similar to Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, catplot

I am working with the Portuguese Bank Marketing dataset
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing#

I would like to visualise the conversion rate per some categorical feature e.g. occupation or marital status.

Using pandas groupby() as show below

```
df.groupby(["marital","y"])["y"].count().plot(kind="bar")
```

I obtain the following graph
[image]

However, I would like to create a more readable graph, similar to the ones in seaborn tutorials.
Where X is some categorical feature, Y is some value and the Hue groups them per some other metric.
[image]

My attempts so far result in the following errors:

```
sns.catplot(x = df["job"].value_counts().index, 
            y = df["job"].value_counts().values, 
            hue="y", 
            data=df, 
            kind="bar")

ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

df.groupby(['sex', 'class']).size().unstack().plot.bar()

# also
# pd.crosstab(df['sex'], df['class']).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not necessarily. Both have very similar syntax
`sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", kind="bar", data=titanic)`
As per https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html


Regardless whether I use sns.barplot or sns.catplot(kind = "bar"), I cannot produce the graph!

Comment: is it `df.groupby(["marital","y"])["y"].count().unstack().plot(kind="bar")`

Comment: It is precisely that!!!! 
Thank you very much Quang!

However, I am still wondering how to do so using Seaborn, as lets be honest, it looks much much nicer than pandas plotting!

Nonetheless, this is precisely what I was looking for! 
I was unaware of the unstack() method!